# Format timespan with hours going above 24 instead of using a days part

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic .NET, I am trying to convert time elapsed in seconds to hh:mm:ss format which can go over 24 hours.

As an example, when try to convert 86400 seconds to a timespan with the following code:

```
dim sec = 86400
dim res = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec).ToString
```

the output is **"1.00:00:00"**

while the desired output for me is **"24:00:00"**

How is it possible to do so?

Comment: You're asking about formatting, not converting. [TimeSpan.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) ` alone uses the general short timespan format ('g'). There's no [standard format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) for what you want. Typically,  you'd need to use a  [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) but there's no specifier for total hours

Comment: BTW If you want to create a timespan for 1 day, `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)` is just easier

Comment: Why do you want this? `24:00` typically refers to the end-of-day in 24H/Military time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I don't recall there being a 24:00 in the military, The clock ran from 00:00:00 - 23:59:59.99999999.

Comment: @dbasnett [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock), specifically [Military Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Military_time). There are other names too. `24:00` has a real meaning, completely different from infiinte 9s. Airline schedules are actually posted in 24-hour time because end-of-day for Monday is a *different* time slot from start-of-day Tuesday

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - have you ever seen a flight at 2400, or 12:00 midnight?  One of the major purposes of the 24 hour clock is to alleviate the confusion around midnight.  I was in the military and never once saw 2400.

Comment: @dbasnett me too, and I've never seen infinite nines. Only developers use infinite nines. But I also work for an Online Travel Agent, so I *know* that GDSs send `24:00` for departure/arrival days in their web service responses. I wrote the code that handles those values. That's how I found out that `24:00` has a special business meaning

Comment: @dbasnett as for the meaning of the phrase `military time` you'll have to take that up with Wikipedia and the Oxford dictionary. The links are in the Wikipedia section on `Military Time`. There's even a section on [Midnight 00:00 and 24:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do the calculation:

```
Dim secs = 86400
Dim ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs)
Dim res = String.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)

Console.WriteLine(res)
```

Outputs:

> 24:00:00

If you want at least two digits for the hours, use `"{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}"`.

(You could use `String.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)` if you think it looks better.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works perfectly, however, for example, for 61 seconds it returns "0:01:01" while the desirable output is "00:01:01". How can I overcome that? Thanks

Comment: It is solved by simply modified as follow: 

String.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)

Comment: @amirhosseinsarfi You're welcome :) I added how to format the hours with at least two digits to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask isn't available either as a [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) or [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8).

You want to emit the total hours as a rounded-down integer followed by the minutes and seconds part. The custom format specifiers only work for specific parts.

You can use the [TimeSpan.TotalHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.8) property to retrieve the hours as a double and format the rest of the string using custom specifiers.

```
Dim ts=TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:mm\:ss}",Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts)
```

Or

```
Dim ts=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(61)
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:mm\:ss}",Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts)
```